# Is Line of code also Line of text?

Tags: language-agnostic, lines-of-code

I know this maybe a silly question I'm quite confuse about them, as I understand this example has 1 line of code and 2 line of text.

```
1. System.out.print("-----------
2. ----------------------------"};
```

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: depends on how it's counted. usually, tools like `wc -l` count this as 2 lines, since they don't bother to parse the actual syntax.

Comment: so literally, they are different?

Comment: well, how would you define "line of code"? example: `if (cond) f();` can be typeset in one or two physical lines -- how many lines of code would it be in either case?

Comment: eg. when we use debugging tool, the above example is a line of code, a completed and meaningful sentence...

Comment: 1 line of code? and what about `if (cond) { f(); }`, which is usually split into 4 lines of text -- is it still 1 line of code?

Comment: to me, i understand them as 02 line of codes.. what do you think ?

Comment: well, there are always corner cases, like comma operator in C++ or lambda expression in C#. I would say, the LOC is mostly meaningless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18316/discussion-between-aptos-and-vlad)

Answer (score 0):

For java I usually define lines of code as the number of non-text semi-colons and right parenthesis.

Comment: so it means that with the above example, your calculated LOC will be 1?